# UIimage will not move on btn press, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to move a UIImage, first button press creates the image and second press moves it.

The image only needs to exist upon pressing the button.

In the simulator it creates the button and places it, the second time it click just doesn't do anything.

This is my Code

```
- (IBAction) btn:(id)sender {

    UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"keyframe"];

    if (startUp == 1){

        //Create Image and add to view
        myImage.frame = CGRectMake(200, 300, 10, 10);
        myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"keyframe"];
        [self.view addSubview:myImage];

        //Set startUp to 0 and output rect value
        startUp = 0;
        NSLog(@"currentFrame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(myImage.frame));

    }else if (startUp == 0){

        //Change position, size and log to debug
        myImage.frame = CGRectMake(500,100 ,20, 20);
        NSLog(@"newFrame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(myImage.frame));
    }
}
```

How do you programmatically move a programmatically added UIimage?
I tried changing the center value but that doesn't work either.

Comment: This has absolutely **nothing** to do with Xcode. As to the question, think about what your action handler method does. You are creating the image view **twice.**

Comment: The reason why it sais Xcode, is because im using Xcode for the programming. I'm fairly new to programming, i thought this code would work, could you get me in the right direction coding this simple action?

Comment: @Seerdar If you used another IDE or no IDE at all for writing your code, the question and the problem would have been the same. -- The solution: don't create the button twice.

Comment: @H2CO3 From your comments and the example below. I understand what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this – tested and working sample:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    BOOL startUp;

    UIImageView *myImage;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    startUp = YES;
}

- (IBAction)doWork:(id)sender {
    if (startUp) {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"keyframe"];
        myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: img];

        [myImage sizeToFit];

        [myImage setCenter: CGPointMake(200, 300)];

        [self.view addSubview: myImage];

        startUp = NO;
    } else {
        [myImage setCenter: CGPointMake(400, 500)];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: To improve this code - move creation and adding image to the viewDidLoad method, and in doWork only change the center.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! I'm creating another "keyframe with x,y value's" could you point me in the direction of how i can add an Bezier Curve between those 2 x,y co-ordinates? The reason for the curve is that I need to read the data of the curve between the two points. An example, keyframe1 is on x: 10  and keyframe2 is on x:70 i want to create a bezier between the two values and read the eased values in between 10 and 70 from the curve.

Comment: Getting into Bezier Curves is a different kettle of fish. Please ask that as a separate question, and mark this one as answered.  Thank you, and good luck!